# After initial link is open the window does not reload 2nd click link in IE and Chrome works fine in Firefox

Tags: javascript

Code:

```
<html>


<body>

<button onclick="myFunction();this.target='_blank';" >Reload page</button>


<a onclick="myFunction(5);location.reload()" >Page 5</a>
<a onclick="myFunction(6);location.reload()" >Page 6</a>



<script>

function myFunction(num) {

    window.open("http://inpathways.net/cbseniors.pdf#page="+num,target='popup','true');

}




</script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `windows.open()` you should use `window.location.href`. Example:

`window.location.href = "http://inpathways.net/cbseniors.pdf#page=" + ("some value");`

Comment: Thank You One more question with my initial code I had the link open another window how do I accomplish this with the new code

Comment: You do need to use `window.open("#target", "_blank")` or in the `a` tag you need to use a `target="_blank"` and use the `href` attribute.